# trigger authentication success event after registration in symfony2.1

Tags: authentication, event-handling, registration, symfony-2.1

After registration I ensure the user is logged in as follows:

```php
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'secured_area', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

and was hoping that this would also trigger my success handler:

```php
$this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(
    AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS,
    new AuthenticationEvent($token)
);
```

The handler is set on the standard form login within the security config, e.g.

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        form_login:
            success_handler: authentication_handler
```

The success handler is triggered fine when logging in but not after registration.

Is this just a config problem? and/or could all of this be achieved with a single event?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to authenticate the user to trigger the event:

```
$token = $this->get('my.bundle.authentication.manager')->authenticate(new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'secured_area', $user->getRoles()));
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

`my.bundle.authentication.manager` would be an alias of `security.authentication.manager`, it could be register like this (XML):

```
<service id="my.bundle.authentication.manager" alias="security.authentication.manager" />
```